# Change screen timeout via Android terminal

Tags: android, android-settings

I need to change screen timeout via Android terminal.

Is there any solution how can I do this?

Comment: check this link if your devices is rooted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/9aDv9MPWx4M

Comment: check this link: https://www.mail-archive.com/android-porting@googlegroups.com/msg15925.html

Comment: @Recall, Thanks. Yeah, I have rooted device)

Comment: @Luca Ziegler thanks, I'll try both ways!